# Building an MVC web application using the Database First approach with an Oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-membership

Mapping membership provider tables in Dev to newly created Oracle tables.

I am building a Internet Application in MVC using Database First Approach (ADO.NET) with an Oracle DB.  Utilizing the MVC 4/Internet Application Template Visual Studio builds a Context Class for the Membership Provider services..  Once you register an account in the App, Visual Studios then creates a Database with the membership tables on your local.. My question is, If I create those tables in an Oracle DB on a server, how do I then MAP my application to use the ORACLE tables.  It appears the MAPPING currently happens in WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity Class...  If I am going at this wrong, please provide me with the best approach..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?  In specific... which membership provider are you using? Is this Simplemembership and not Identity?

Comment: T.S.  Thanks for your reply... I am using MVC 4 and  it's identity not simple membership, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map that on App.config.
Where you see HOST on data source, you define the path to your oracle server.

[image]

You can find more information on this link:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html

Comment: Hey Thiago.. Thanks for your reply... I should have mentioned that I already used ADO.NET To build the model and a new Context.. So the ODAC Is working as expected with a few tweaks... The problem is now I have two Context.. The one the ADO.NET wizard created and the one Created by the framework for the membership providers...  The context for the membership is mapped to a localDb, while the other is mapped to my oracle tables...   So the question is, how do I point that one to Oracle membership tables.. I hope that clears up the misunderstand.. Thanks

Comment: I guess the question should read... How do u implement Identity classes and tables in an oracle database for authentication and security... Thanks...

Comment: digiShadoe - I believe you should pass the Oracle DB context as Constructor parameter for the table classes that you need to use. Then you will reference that as:  using (var context = new OracleContext()) 
{     
    // Perform data access using the context 
}